# ci bonfire move complete website to another folder

Tags: codeigniter, directory, move

I want to move my website from example.com to example.com/new . This website is built on CI Bonfire by another developer. I'm new to CI Bonfire and tried a lot many change in config.php but could not get success. Kindly let me know steps involved so that I can solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Following are the steps.

- Copy all files to new server
- Create database to new server.
- Import the existing database file to new server database.
- Change the database settings the config/database.php file. Set username, password, database name and host.
- Change `$config['base_url']` in config.php file and check all the file permissions.